# How to align equations to the left side?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, errors

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 with Texmaker
and I'm trying to left align some equations like these:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{flalign}
 a)   I_g : N_{log} \rightarrow M\left(p, p, \phi \right) \mbox{is
compact.} \nonumber \\
 b)   I_g : N_{log}^0 \rightarrow M\left(p, p, \phi \right) \mbox{is
compact.} \nonumber \\
 c)   \int \limits _ {\mathbb{D}}   \frac{\left(g
\left(z\right)\right)^p}{log \left( \frac{2}{1- \mid z \mid
^2}\right)^p}   \frac{\phi^p \left(|z|\right)}{1- \mid z \mid } d
A(z) < \infty .
\end{flalign}
```

I get the message:

```
Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.
```

Comment: If I extend your code snippet to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) adding `\documentclass{article}`, `\usepackage{amsfonts}`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` I cannot reproduce your problem. So please extend your code snippet to a MWE that shows the problem.

Comment: Did you maybe place the `flalign` environment inside an `equation` environment?

Comment: You can use the `fleqn` option for the documentclass. With it all equations from `align` and similar environments are left aligned with an indent of the length `\mathindent`.

Answer (score 10):

I see this an abuse of `flalign`: your readers will have a hard time at guessing whether the number refers to all three conditions or just to the integral.

You could use `aligned`, so the number would be vertically centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]% stands for text before the display
\begin{flalign}
&\begin{aligned}
\text{a)}&\quad I_g \colon N_{\log} \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is compact.} \\
\text{b)}&\quad I_g \colon N_{\log}^0 \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is compact.} \\
\text{c)}&\quad \int\limits_{\mathbb{D}}
                \frac{(g(z))^p}{\log\bigl(\frac{2}{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}\bigr)^p}
                \frac{\phi^p (\lvert z\rvert)}{1-\lvert z\rvert}\,dA(z) < \infty.
\end{aligned}&&
\end{flalign}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might consider the following `subequations` approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]% stands for text before the display
\begin{subequations}\label{global}
\begin{align}
\label{particular-a}
& I_g \colon N_{\log} \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is compact.} \\
\label{particular-b}
& I_g \colon N_{\log}^0 \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is compact.} \\
\label{particular-c}
& \int\limits_{\mathbb{D}}
    \frac{(g(z))^p}{\log\bigl(\frac{2}{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}\bigr)^p}
    \frac{\phi^p (\lvert z\rvert)}{1-\lvert z\rvert}\,dA(z) < \infty.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `\eqref{global}` for referring to the common number, but also `\eqref{particular-c}` for referring to the third condition.

Answer (score 5):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

Like @Schweinebacke, I am unable to replicate the error message you say you're getting if I use only the partial information you've provided so far. Absent additional information, my *hunch* is that the `flalign` environment is embedded in another display-math environment in your real document, but not in the code snippet.

You should really take some time to clean up your code. Don't overuse `\left` and `\righ`t, do not use `\mid` to generate absolute-value "fences", do learn the difference between `:` and `\colon` in math mode, and do write `\log` rather than just `log` to denote the logarithm operator, and do learn how to use `&` to align rows in an `flalign` environment.

The following screenshot provides a before-and-after code-cleanup comparison.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\setlength\textwidth{3.5in} % just for this example
\begin{document}

Before:
\begin{flalign}
 a)   I_g : N_{log} \rightarrow M\left(p, p, \phi \right) \mbox{is
compact.} \nonumber \\
 b)   I_g : N_{log}^0 \rightarrow M\left(p, p, \phi \right) \mbox{is
compact.} \nonumber \\
 c)   \int \limits _ {\mathbb{D}}   \frac{\left(g
\left(z\right)\right)^p}{log \left( \frac{2}{1- \mid z \mid
^2}\right)^p}   \frac{\phi^p \left(|z|\right)}{1- \mid z \mid } d
A(z) < \infty .
\end{flalign}

After:
\begin{flalign}
 &a)\quad I_g \colon N_{\log}   \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is
compact.} \nonumber \\
 &b)\quad I_g \colon N_{\log}^0 \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is
compact.} \nonumber \\
 &c)\quad \int\limits_{\mathbb{D}} \! \frac{\bigl(g(z)\bigr)^p}{
 \log \bigl( 2/(1-\lvert z\rvert^2) \bigr)^p}\,   
 \frac{\phi^p (\lvert z\rvert)}{1-\lvert z\rvert} \,d A(z) < \infty .
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to left-align only *some* equations, you have the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` and `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\text{a)}&\enspace & & I_g \colon N_{\log} \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is compact.} \\
\text{b)}& & & I_g \colon N_{\log}^0 \rightarrow M(p, p, \phi) \text{ is compact.} \\
\text{c)}& & & \int\limits_{\mathbb{D}}
                \frac{(g(z))^p}{\log\bigl(\frac{2}{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}\bigr)^p}
                \frac{\phi^p (\lvert z\rvert)}{1-\lvert z\rvert}\,dA(z) < \infty.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]